# How to initialize an external reference in Thymeleaf?

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

If I had a Java class called for instance Buffet and one of its fields was something like:

```
@ManyToOne
private Chef chef
```

and I had to create a new Buffet object in an html form using Thymeleaf, how would I be able to refer to this chef field? At the moment my html looks like this:

```
<form th:action="@{/newBuffet}" method="POST" th:object="${buffet}">
    <div>
        <div>
            <span><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="name"/></span>
        </div>      
        <div>
            <span><input type="text" th:field="*{chef}" placeholder="chef"/></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span><button type="submit">Invio<i class="material-icons">done</i></button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and my controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newBuffet", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String formBuffet (Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("buffet", new Buffet());
    return "newBuffet.html";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/newBuffet", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addBuffet (@ModelAttribute("buffet") Buffet b, Model model) {
    this.buffetService.save(b);
    model.addAttribute("buffets", this.buffetService.listBuffets());
    return "buffets.html";
}
```

the error it gives is, of course, because of the way Thymeleaf's input takes only strings whilst my input is an instance of my class Chef.

Comment: Either using a sepperate bean for view that has Chef as a string field and parsing it in service, Or changing the chef input to a select should work

Comment: I've tried using a select with a th:each inside the options. Only problem is I have no clue of how select passes back the selected option to the controller so that I can save it (I've tried with @ RequestParam and a simple @ ModelAttribute but it didn't work)

Comment: Should use something like `<option th:each="chef : ${chefs}" th:text="${chef.name} th:id="${chef.id} />` and the controller should pass that to a Chef object with only id set, and when saving hibernate is able to persist that asuming everything is set up correctly

Comment: I still don't know how this parameter gets passed from my view to my controller. If I had something like a string or an id in my controller (say as either a RequestParam or a ModelAttribute) to then search in my chefRepository for the instance I'm looking for it would solve my problem.